# Parsing JSON Array to print specific elements

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, networking

Im currently trying to parse JSON data from this api in JS but im not sure how to. As of right now when I press any buttons to give me the data, it prints the arrays out rather than the specific data I want. Ive tried to use the JSON Parse function to retrieve the specific data but it seems its not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated! URL to the API docs: https://www.balldontlie.io/#get-all-players

```js
//Loads Player Data
function loadPlayers() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("players").innerHTML =
        this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players", true);



    var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

    console.log(data["last_name"])

    xhttp.send();

  }


  //Loads Game Data
  function loadGames() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("games").innerHTML =
        this.responseText;      
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/games", true);
    xhttp.send();
  }

  //Loads Team Data
  function loadTeams() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("teams").innerHTML =
        this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/teams", true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:peachpuff;" >

<center>NBA STATS</center>
<center><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right" scrollamount="12.5">Data Extracted From BDL API</marquee></center>
<center>    <a href="https://www.balldontlie.io/#introduction">View API Docs</a>   </center>

<script src="main.js"></script>
    
<div id="players">  
<button type="button" onclick="loadPlayers()">View Players</button>
</div>
   

<div id = "teams" >
<button type="button2" onclick="loadTeams()">View Teams</button>
</div>



<div id ="games">
<button type="button3" onclick="loadGames()">View Games</button>   
<div>
    





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You should parse JSON in `xhttp.onreadystatechange`, that's a callback when request data success.
2. For the players data as example, it is an object with `data` and `meta`, and the players is in `data` key which is an Array, so you need to loop inside the array to print the values that you needed.

Here's the example for `loadPlayers()`. You can apply the same concept to `loadGames` and `loadTeams`, please let me know if you still having questions.

```js
function loadPlayers() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            // parse JSON after response
            var players = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            // get 'data' key inside response
            var playersData = players.data;

            // loop all the players
            for (var player of playersData) {
                // print last_name to the #players element
                document.getElementById("players").innerHTML += "<br />" + player['last_name'];
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In function loadPlayers()
data is an array not object